# PCB burned board repair advice needed

Tags: pcb

While I was using a voltage meter to test the output of the battery pin connectors, I accidentally touch both positive and negative terminal pins which resulted in burns on a PCB board.

I am hoping the problem is clear and that it can be repaired.

I have attached some photos and would request anyone who can point me in the right direction on how to fix the problem?

I have some experience with electronics but I don’t really know what to do.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks

[image: top]
[image: bottom]

Comment: You might need to draw a circle around the area you think is damaged. I can't see it after looking for 10 s. Please be aware that repair posts without good technical content are quickly closed as off topic. See [Tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/Tour).

Comment: 1) next time, use probes which only have a small metal pin exposed 2) I do not see any "burn" spots. It might be that the "magic smoke" escaped from one or more components. When the magic smoke escapes, components usually no longer work.

Comment: What prompted you to do this?  Li-Ion charger not working? Not Seqwaying fast enough? too short a ride time?  ( too short a gap)

Comment: Could you mark the position where it burned? I highly doubt that the broken soldermask is the spot, because it doesn't look burned and seems to be a ground plane (your battery would have exploded at the current thst is required to burn heaten a groudplane that much)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like excessive current burned the solder mask off, but the copper appears to still be intact. If the board is still functional you could probably just remove the copper pour over the burned area with an X-acto knife (cut and peel it back) to prevent leakage through the damaged PCB material.

[image]

However, if the short has damaged parts on the board (quite likely, depending on the path it took) you'll be looking at much more of job and probably skills you don't have, to troubleshoot and replace the damaged parts (if spares are even available).

Answer (score 1):

Use the continuity function of your multimeter to test the parts in the current path.
Things that are usually damaged when similar things happen:

- Fuses
- Fuseable resistors & regular resistors
- PTC fuses
- Transistors
- Diodes

Try googling or finding a service manual of the damaged part, if you can't find them whoever made it usually provides one (or assistance). 
For further questions, post clearer pictures of what you think might be damaged (bloated capacitors, weird solder spots etc), because otherwise it's pointless.

Good luck.

Edit:
To test Bipolar transistors, set the multimeter for continuity (diode symbol) and measure the voltage between the three pins. 2 of them should have a positive or negative voltage drop of about a diode or so. The remaining combination should test as an open circuit.

MOSFETs/FETs are a bit trickier to test on board, so try to check everything else and narrow down the issue before going there.

Answer (score 0):

Although these FETs can handle single surges of 500 A for 100 us , or 190 mJ of energy , if the device has a Joule energy reactance load greater than this, before shutdown or fusing , it will have failed components, fused traces , shorted FETs from a charge dump say from battery connection.